# Android: Intent open the wrong activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm working on a widget for an Android app and I encounter a problem. When the user click on the widget, I'd like the application to open his first activity (the one with intent-filter: 'action.MAIN' / 'category.LAUNCHER') (I'll call it Activity A).

To do that, I use this snippet (in my WidgetProvider class):

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.view , pendingIntent);
```

This works very good if my application is killed or if all the activities have been closed (using the back button until the application close)

The problem happen when several activities are open. Imagine the activity stack is like : Activity **A** -> Activity **B** -> Activity **C**.
If I click on the widget, **SOMETIMES** the application is just brought to front and Activity **C** is visible instead of Activity **A**.
It's very strange because this doesn't happen every time. (It seems that it happen after I navigate a lot in activities)

I really need the activity A to open and not another activity whatever how the activity stack was because this activity is like a hub with several links to differents fonctionnalities.

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much.

PS: Sorry if my English is pretty poor, I'm from Belgium

Comment: couldn't you just call finish() as you launch your next activity? It should not re-appear.

Comment: This is not conceivable. If I do this, the application will stop as soon as the user press the back button.

Answer (score 3):

From a widget you should do more or less the same as the system launcher does with intents.

Try using [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in your intent. You will also want to look at `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

It's better to follow [the platform guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#into-your-app) by the way, which say that you can also inject deep into your app, provided you give the user the right path to navigate up again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific Activity to launch, why don't you just call that activity specifically, instead of dynamically.

You are experiencing issues due to the Activities in your back-stack.  Android manages the life-cycle of your Activities in a very special way that you should probably research - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle

calling finish() - will always return to the activity that launched the current activity.  The only time your app will close, is if there was not an original activity.  You could always test for this condition, and if the calling activity is NULL, you could explicitly call you Activity A.

Comment: I'm aware about the way Android manages the activities. The problem is that when I call the activity I want to open (Even explicitely, in this case, Activity A) from my widget, sometimes the application open the Activity C (if the Activity stack is A-B-C)